# Recursively generate sql statement

Tags: php, sql, pear

I'm using PHP & PEAR DB for database abstraction.
I have an array of id's `$id`. I want to create an sql statement using PEAR's query() placeholders that updates all the rows referenced in the $id variable to a single value.

Something to the effect of:

```
$sql = $conn->query('UPDATE guest SET role = ? WHERE id = ?', array(1, $id)
```

so that it passes a single value to role and multiple values to id.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourIDlist = array (1,2); 
$sql = $conn->query("UPDATE guest SET role = 'MY ROLE' WHERE id IN (".join(",",$yourIDlist).")");
```

you can use your ID array with the IN and join function